# reading the scala spec for expressions

Tags: scala, scalac

I must have missed where the notation used [here in the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#expressions) is defined. As a case in point it would be very helpful completely deciphering the first two rows of it:

```
Expr         ::=  (Bindings | id | `_') `=>' Expr
               |  Expr1
```

I am rather clueless where is `id` defined, and about the syntax (and hence interpretation) of this notation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is from [the lexical grammar](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/13-syntax-summary.html#lexical-syntax).  Succinctly, it is:

```
upper            ::=  ‘A’ | … | ‘Z’ | ‘$’ | ‘_’  // and Unicode category Lu
lower            ::=  ‘a’ | … | ‘z’ // and Unicode category Ll
letter           ::=  upper | lower // and Unicode categories Lo, Lt, Nl
digit            ::=  ‘0’ | … | ‘9’
opchar           ::= // printableChar not matched by (whiteSpace | upper | lower |
                     // letter | digit | paren | delim | opchar | Unicode_Sm | Unicode_So)

op               ::=  opchar {opchar}
varid            ::=  lower idrest
plainid          ::=  upper idrest
                 |  varid
                 |  op
id               ::=  plainid
                 |  ‘`’ stringLiteral ‘`’
idrest           ::=  {letter | digit} [‘_’ op]
```

`Bindings` is defined further down [in the context-free syntax](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/13-syntax-summary.html#context-free-syntax), but is defined in [Chapter 2](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html)

> Names in Scala identify types, values, methods, and classes which are collectively called entities. Names are introduced by local definitions and declarations, inheritance, import clauses, or package clauses which are collectively called bindings.

#### But what does it *mean*

In informal language:

```
Expr ::= (Bindings | id | `_') `=>' Expr
         |  Expr1
```

could be written as:

> An `Expr` shall be taken to mean (`::=`) either (`(...)`) a `Bindings`, an `id`, or a literal underscore character (`'_'`), followed by the equals and right-angle-bracket characters (`'=>'`), followed by either an `Expr` or an `Expr1`.

In even *more* informal language still, you could say:

> An Expression (`Expr`) is any valid binding syntax (either a magic `_` or a normal variable reference, one or more times, possibly with type ascriptions) or a variable reference, or just a magic `_`, followed by an arrow (`=>`), followed by any expression we allow in the language

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the non-terminal `id` is defined but hopefully I can help you understand the notation.

The notation looks like [Backus-Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form). It means that an `Expr` is one of the following:

1. `Bindings '=>' Expr`
2. `id '=>' Expr`
3. `'_' '=>' Expr`
4. `Expr1`

Tokens in `'` quotes are string literals, whereas tokens that aren't quoted are non-terminal, meaning they can be further expanded.

So if I had the following snippet of code:

```
x => x * x
```

Then that might be parsed as something like the following:

```
    Expr
   / |  \
 id '=>' Expr
 |        |
'x'     Expr1
          |
       BinaryOp
       /  |  \
   Expr1 '*' Expr1
     |        |
    id       id
     |        |
    'x'      'x'
```